# Are images included when calculating email size?

Tags: html, email

I just read this [article](https://mailchimp.com/help/gmail-is-clipping-my-email/) that talks about how email clients clip emails that are over a certain size and sometimes even marks them as spam.

Since images are included in most emails using a `<img src="https://www.files/my-image.png">`, would these images be included in the size calculation? They're loaded asynchronously so I'm confused if they would be or not.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the mail service provider. The type of message that you are sending and the recipient - and of course you don't always know the answer! You can embed, you can encode and you can include links to images. It's impossible to expect everyone to get the emails you want to send!

For instance HTML emails. Who would know if the email you send will survive the process? There is so much that could go wrong.

When using images in an email I try to go for one picture and a logo as a max, with the text set up to appear early on and to get to the point. If I have a long message, I will want to tease it on the email, get the click and have my recipient come to a landing page where I have much more space and much tighter control.

This I find increases my open rates etc, most importantly, it tends to be the way that gets the most people to take action. I  do like to use styled HTML. This means that the emails look good yet the focus is on the text so if the style does not survive the transmission, the message still gets through.

You have some choices!